# Forwarding e-mails to a website?

Tags: php, email

I have an e-mail address that is signed up to a list-serv and I would like to set up a script to monitor it.  If it gets an e-mail addressed to the list-serv, I would like to have the contents dumped to a secure webpage a user would log into (in a blog-style output, making it almost like one big thread for a forum) so that all of the e-mails are in a central location.

I'm pretty sure php has this type of capability, but I'm new to web dev so was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction of how I could go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you email provider supports IMAP you can use [PHP IMAP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php) to do this.

Comment: I was just planning on setting up a dummy account with a free provider (gmail, hotmail, etc). Do these support IMAP?

Comment: Gmail supports IMAP:  http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78799